# Getting all latitudes and longitudes from two co-ordinates

Tags: java, google-maps, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Can anyone please tell how to get all the latitudes and longitudes points in between two co-ordinates in Google map
i.e

**From**

Latitude : 10.013482
Longitude : 76.331323

**To**

Latitude : 10.005135
Longitude : 76.313385

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i'm using jsp............java

Comment: I've retagged your question, you might get a better response now.

Comment: There are an infinite number of points in a line. Do you want to draw the line?  What do you need the coordinates for?

Comment: i want all the coordinates in between that....is it possible to find all points....in order to test one of my google path tracking application

Comment: What @geocodezip said... if you had a vertical line between say (10.005135,76.331323) and (10.013482,76.331323).  Given that you've got 6 decimal places, you'd have points at each of 10.005136, 10.005137, 10.005138, 10.005139, ... up to 10.013482

Comment: I am wondering if there is an issue with language.  Imagine you are walking from point 1 to point 2.  How many steps you took would be the number of points between point 1 and 2.  Now walk the path again with half the step size.  You now have twice as many points.  You could divide the distance by however many steps you want.  Practically speaking, you choose a step size and march along the bearing to the new point.  This is called a range-bearing problem.  Is this what you are asking or do you want path error?

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you are asking.
You want all the points between 10.005135 and 10.013482 that are also between 76.313385 and 76.331323.
Forget that they are coordinates and it is a simple math problem.  Of course the results could be quite large.